# Fetching data from store if exists or call API otherwise in React

Tags: reactjs, redux

Let's assume I have a component called BookOverview that displays details of a book.

I'm getting data with an action:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getBook(areaId);
  }
```

And then I get the data with axios:

```
export const getBook = () => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.get(
    `${API}/${ENDPOINT}`
  );

  dispatch({
    type: GET_BOOK,
    payload: res.data
  });
};
```

How shall I change this code to:

1. if redux store already have the book loaded - return it
2. if no book is present in the store - call the relevant API?

What is the best practise to achieve that please?

Answer (score 4):

You can have the `getState` inside your **async action creator** like this:

```
export const getBook = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  if(!getState().book /* check if book not present */) {
    const res = await axios.get(
      `${API}/${ENDPOINT}`
    );

    dispatch({
      type: GET_BOOK,
      payload: res.data
    });
  } else {
    dispatch({
      type: GET_BOOK,
      payload: getState().book
    });
  }
};
```

For More [Async Actions-Redux](https://redux.js.org/advanced/asyncactions#actions-js-with-fetch)

Comment: Just for the case, the modern way to do that with amazin explain. https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createasyncthunk

Answer (score 1):

You can try it this way:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    if(this.props.book==null){
       this.props.getBook(areaId);
    }
  }
```

I assumed that you have a property called `book` in your props. that populates from the particular reducer.
You have to subscribe the particular reducer to get the `this.props.book` - This gives the value that you have in your store.