# Redux: Why does my useEffect() keeps rerendering its value on every page rerender

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-dom, redux-thunk

I am learning `react-redux`.
I got the following problem:

1. I make two async api calls (with `redux-thunk`):

- the first one to fetch country names (in one object, ex: `{countries: [{...}, ...]}`.

2. Those country names I use afterwards to make a second api call, to get all the soccer leagues, that are in those countrys (sometimes, there are none, so I get a `null`). In this case, the call is made with each countryName separatly. I make out of the results an array.
3. This arrays length is 255m out of which I filter out the `null` values and map the leagues names.
4. After I click on a League's name, a page is rendered (`{Link} from "react-router-dom";`).
   **NOW my problem occurs**
5. When I click, to get back to my home page (`<Link to={"/"} >`), both `useEffect()` are making an api call again. Why?

Here is the code for my `useEffect()`:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const selectAllCountries = useSelector(state => state.allCountries);
const selectAllLeagues = useSelector(state => state.allLeagues);

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(allCountries());
}, [dispatch]);

useEffect(() => {
    if(!_.isEmpty(selectAllCountries.data)) {
        selectAllCountries.data.countries.map(el => dispatch(allLeagues(el.name_en)));
    }
}, [dispatch, selectAllCountries.data]);
```

I tried to make a custom hook and put the `useEffect()` in there:

```
const useCountries = getCountries => {useEffect(() => {
dispatch(getCountries());
},[getCountries])}

useCountries(allCountries);
```

as suggested here:
[React hooks: dispatch action from useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54930197/react-hooks-dispatch-action-from-useeffect)

But it didnt help.

Will be greatful for any help.

---

ANSWER:

in "./actions/.../allLeagues.js

```
...
import _ from "lodash";

export const allLeagues = (country) => async (dispatch, getState) => {

    if (!_.isEmpty(getState().allLeagues) && !_.isEmpty(getState().allLeagues.data)) {
        return Promise.resolve();
    } else {
        try {

          ...
        
        }
    }    
}
```

Question, that was also helpfull:
[Fetching data from store if exists or call API otherwise in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53113449/fetching-data-from-store-if-exists-or-call-api-otherwise-in-react)
(take look at answer about `getStore()`)

Comment: the component is being unmounted and mounted again when you change routes, so is the expected behaviour

Comment: This would explain a lot. Thanks.
Is there a way to ommit it? I can think of putting the `useEffect`'s in another container.

Comment: that will work, if it is moved to a higher level in the tree to avoid dispatching every time you enter that route, or implement some kind of caching

Comment: Now, when I know, for what to search for, I found a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53113449/fetching-data-from-store-if-exists-or-call-api-otherwise-in-react

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment above, the homepage unmounts when you click to go to a new page. When you go back, the page re-mounts and the effect runs again, triggering another API call. You can prevent the API call by checking whether or not the values already exist in your store. I personally like to do this in the action creator, but you could do it in the effect as well.

Checking state in the action creator:

```js
function allLeagues(countryName) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    // Call `getState` and check whether `allLeagues` has been populated yet.
    const { allLeagues } = getState();

    if (allLeagues && allLeagues.data && allLeagues.data.length) {
      // You already have the data, no need to make the API call.
      return Promise.resolve();
    }

    // No data, make the API call...
  };
}
```

Checking state in the effect:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // Check whether the league data is set or not.
  if(!_.isEmpty(selectAllCountries.data) && _.isEmpty(selectAllLeagues.data)) {
    selectAllCountries.data.countries.map(el => dispatch(allLeagues(el.name_en)));
  }
}, [dispatch, selectAllCountries.data, selectAllLeagues.data]);
```

Comment: Thats it. I chose the action variant (will post my answer in the end of my question). Now, that I know about `getStore()` it makes things easier. Thank you!